# Cannot connect to router interface: connection refused

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

Known fact:

1. The router sticker says interface is `192.168.0.100`, however my Mac has an IP `10.10.2.86` and says my router has an IP `10.10.1.1`
2. (When connected the router using a wire) I ping `192.168.0.100`:

   > request timeout.

   When I ping `10.10.1.1`:

   > 64 bytes from 10.10.1.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=1.055 ms
3. (Wired) I attempt to visit `10.10.1.1`, I get:

   > ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
4. The router is Netgear N150 Access Point WN604.

Troubleshooting

1. I reset and restarted the router. The SSID of it changes to default NETGEAR_11ng, password gone, the above facts remain true. Still cannot visit its interface.

Comment: Have you tried another browser? Some routers are very particular about which browsers they will allow connections from.

Comment: Yes, I've tried Chrome and Safari on my Mac, and Safari on my iPhone. None seem to work.

Comment: An access point is not a router, by the way. Depending on what you want to accomplish, you won’t be able to accomplish it by changing its configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Cannot connect to router interface

You are using the wrong IP Address, try 192.168.0.230.

> **Cannot Connect to the Access Point to Configure It**
>
> Check these items:
>
> - The access point is correctly installed, LAN connections are OK, and it is powered on. Check that the LAN port LED is green to verify that
>     the Ethernet connection is OK.
> - **The default configuration of the WN604 is for a static IP address of 192.168.0.230 and a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 with DHCP disabled. Make sure your network configuration settings are correct.**
> - If you are using the NetBIOS name of the access point to connect, ensure that your computer and the access point are on the same network
>     segment or that there is a WINS server on your network.
> - If your computer is set to obtain an IP address automatically (DHCP client), restart it.
> - If your computer uses a fixed (static) IP address, ensure that it is using an IP address in the range of the WN604. The access point
>     default IP address is 192.168.0.230, and the default subnet mask is
>     255.255.255.0.

Source [User Manual](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/WN604/WN604_UM_15July2013.pdf)

Comment: After changing IPv4 configuration to "Manually" and change the IP Address to 192.168.0.230, Subnet Mask to 255.255.255.0, and Router to 192.168.0.100, I was able to visit the setting interface. I should've searched for the user manual, but thanks!